# Heroku Won't Run "Rake" Commands

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, rake

[image]

This literally just happened, and won't go away -- anyone had any similar experiences or a fix?

Many thanks!

Comment: can't you use `heroku run rake`?

Comment: Sorry, yes I used that. The screen I posted was me testing `heroku ___`. Same error both times :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `heroku run` to run your rake commands but don't do it with assets:precompile. That happens already when you deploy. If you need to precompile your assets, do it locally, commit the compiled files and deploy to heroku.

Comment: Hey Diego, thanks for the answer. The problem still persists when using the `heroku run` command

Comment: Even does it for `Heroku run rails c`

Comment: Try updating your heroku client

Comment: Thanks will do that now!

Comment: Also, are you using the command prompt? Try using cygwin so you can have a unix like terminal in windows.

Comment: Updating the Heroku ver fixed it!! Thanks Diego